# Merge several pdfs from several folders in a folder structure to 1 PDF using python

Tags: python, pdf, merge, pypdf

I would like to merge several PDFs into 1 PDF. We are talking about several thousand PDFs. These are additionally stored in different folders. But they are all in 1 main folder

simple example:

```
Main Folder
    Folder 1
        Pdf 1
        Pdf 2
        ...
        PDF 300
    Folder 2
        PDf 343
    Folder 3
        Folder 4
            PDF 123
            Pdf 2123
```

The folders all have different names. Also the files all have unique names. The only thing that is always the same is the file *.PDF

I started with:

```
import os
import glob
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

pdffiles = [os.path.join(root, name) 
             for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Merge_I\\')
             for name in files
             if name.endswith('.pdf')]

merger = PdfFileMerger

for name in pdffiles:
    if name.endswith('.pdf'):
        merger.append(name)

merger.write('C:\\Merge_O\\Test.pdf')
merger.close()
```

*But I get the error*
TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fileobj'

Comment: It should be at least `merger = PdfFileMerger()`, with parentheses, to create an instance...

Comment: Sometimes it is the little things that are missing. :) Thx mate